# Modifying table with javascript that is using Matt Kruse's table sort

Tags: javascript, sorting, tablesort

Over many years, I have found Matt Kruse's Table Sort to be a great solution for sorting and filtering tables, but my current requirement has me hiding/restoring columns dynamically (radio buttons, using javascript), and this seems to corrupt the Matt's table-structures that enable the sorting and filtering.

I have tried both rebuilding the table into .innerhtml, and also modifying the display style. (I have all the table information in arrays, so can rebuild the table if needed.) The table is built from the arrays initially, and Matt's library appears to be happy with that.

I have been going through Matt's code to see how to cause them to re-initialise after I make the changes to the table, but I think the Matt is a couple of steps over my ability. I don't understand how Matt's library code links to the htlm tables.

Can anyone have a quick look at the library and tell me how I can prod them into reinitialising (without reloading the whole page) - 
http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/table/source.php

Comment: That library was last updated in 2007.  That's a _huuuge_ amount of time as far as developments on the web go - you might be better placed to retire it and find something more modern.

Comment: Yes. old, but actually has worked wonderfully well - the only thing that I have ever done is to add another date format to it. It is just this new requirement that is tripping me up. I can start looking around for something else, but what you already know always seems easiest to use  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is REALLY old, but just in case, you can just reinvoke the table.js script as a function after your changes with something like:

```
$.getScript('path_to_my_script/table.js', function() {});
```

That will cause it to run again and apply to any tables/cells with the applicable classes.